# Characterization of peripheral cycles in graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Dear StackExchange Community,

I am struggeling with the several definitions of peripheral cycles in graphs.

Disclaimer: For me it can be assumed that the graph is 3-connected and planar.

To introduce the problem I would like to start with the definition of Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral_cycle)

> A peripheral cycle  $C$ in a graph  $G$ can be defined formally in one of several equivalent ways:

> $C$  is peripheral if it is an induced cycle with the property that the subgraph  $G\setminus C$ formed by deleting the edges and vertices of $C$  is connected. (e.g. used in https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-53622-3)

> If $C$ is any subgraph of $G$, a bridge of $C$ is a minimal subgraph $B$ of $G$ that is edge-disjoint from $C$ and that has the property that all of its points of attachments (vertices adjacent to edges in both  $B$ and $G\setminus B$) belong to $C$. A simple cycle $C$ is peripheral if it has exactly one bridge. (e.g. used in [https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall07/Papers/Tutte63.pdf](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emisha/Fall07/Papers/Tutte63.pdf))

My problem is, that several papers and books uses the first or the second definition, but until now I did not found a paper, who proofs, that both definitions are equivalent. Maybe this relation is too trivial but the references at wikipedia are more like "Someone is using it in the same way".

The nearest proof I found was in (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895604000322?via%3Dihub) Lemma 10 but as the paper wants to deal with infinite graphs it is also difficult to see, if it proofs the relation.

Of course I also could ignore this difference as it is intuitivelly clear, that both definitions are equivalent or I could try to proof it on my own.
But as I am not an expert on graph theory it would be nice to have a citable reference.

Best regards,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I've known cycles with at most one bridge by the name "non-separating", which in my opinion is a clearer description of what they are: they do not separate the graph into more than one piece.

I think there likely is a mistake on Wikipedia, and Wikipedia doe not mention any assumptions about 3-connectivity in their definition. Let $G$ be formed from a cycle $C$ by adding a chord. Then $C$ is not induced in $G$, but it has exactly one bridge, so $C$ is peripheral only according to the second definition.

Moreover, but probably of lesser significance, if $G$ is only composed of a cycle, then $C$ has no bridges. But it is induced. Now, is the null graph connected? Depending on this, the definitions agree or do not agree.

I think that when reading papers you have to deduce which notion they mean. But most of the time, these two notions agree. In fact, if $G$ is 3-connected, these notions agree:

Suppose $C$ is peripheral in the first sense, i.e., $C$ is induced and $G\backslash C$ is connected. Since $G$ is $3$-connected, $G$ contains a $K_4$ minor, so $G\backslash C$ is nonempty, as $G$ has at least $4$ vertices, and any two non-adjacent vertices of $C$ are joined by a path of length at least 2 outside $C$. Thus, $G\backslash C$ and the edges attaching to $C$ form a single bridge. Hence $C$ is peripheral in the second sense.

Suppose $C$ is peripheral in the second sense, i.e., $C$ has one bridge, say $B$. If $B$ is a single edge, then $G$ is not $3$-connected, since vertices not incident to $B$ in $C$ are separated by the ends of $B$. Thus, $B$ contains a vertex. By minimality, $B$ consists of one connected component and its points of attachment, so $G\backslash C$ is connected, i.e., $C$ is peripheral in the first sense.

Comment: Dear Mathieu, thanks for the reply. You are right for the special cases the definitions are not equivalent. In the literature the peripheral cycles are often used to describe faces ofe of polytopes, which are the 3-connected planar graphs. For this case the formulation of the theorems can be found in both descriptions and therefore they should be equivalent. But as I mentioned, I did not found a proof for the characterization right now.

Comment: Added an argument for the two notions being the same under the assumption $G$ is $3$-connected.